# Django 3.2.8 custom middleware returns 302 redirect errors

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-3.2

I am looking to use custom middleware to redirect a user to a their profile role if their profile role value is set to '0'.

Below is the current code I am using, but is causes a 302 redirect loop. This is based on other examples I found on the internet, but no luck in finding a fix.

Any ideas will be greatly valued.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class UserRoleMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_request(self, request):
        redirect_url = '/role/'

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.profile.role == '0':
            print('user must define a role')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

        return None
```

Response:

```
[23/Oct/2021 23:00:50] "GET /role/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
user must define a role
[23/Oct/2021 23:00:50] "GET /role/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
user must define a role
[23/Oct/2021 23:00:50] "GET /role/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
user must define a role
[23/Oct/2021 23:00:50] "GET /role/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the middleware will also be triggered on your `/role/` route, you should put in a check to see if the request path is for that route to avoid the loop.

```py
    def process_request(self, request):
        redirect_url = '/role/'

        if request.path == redirect_url:
            return self.get_response(request)

        # or check for `and request.path != redirect_url` here
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.profile.role == '0':
            print('user must define a role')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

        return None
```

Also, I believe you want to be returning `self.get_response(request)` not `None`.